# Assembly. Reversing word

Tags: assembly

i would like to reverse a word in asm, using stack (For example Testing = gnitseT). I was trying to do it by myself, but my program returns the same string. Help

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char *x = "Teststring";

    asm (
        ".intel_syntax noprefix;"
        "mov eax, %1;"
        "xor bx,bx;"
        "xor ecx,ecx;"
        "pushloop:"
            "mov cl, [eax];"
            "cmp cl, 0;"
            "jz poploop;"
            "inc bx; "
                "push eax;"
                "inc eax;"
                "jmp pushloop;"
        "xor eax,eax;"
        "poploop:"
            "cmp bx, 0;"
            "jz end;"
                "pop eax;"
                "inc eax;"
                "dec bx;"
                "jmp poploop;"
        "end:"

            "mov %0, eax;"

        ".att_syntax prefix;"
     : "=r" (x)
     : "r" (x)
     : "eax","cl"
   );
    printf("x=%s", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For starters, you can't just switch to intel syntax behind the back of the compiler or else all the substitutions will be wrong. If you want to use intel syntax, use `-masm=intel ` command line switch.

Comment: Amongst others: "Teststring" is a string literal. You cannot change its content.

Answer (score 2):

```
"pushloop:"
 "mov cl, [eax];"
 "cmp cl, 0;"
 "jz poploop;"
 "inc bx; "
 "push eax;"
 "inc eax;"
 "jmp pushloop;"
```

In this loop you want to push the character, so push the ECX register. Not the address in EAX.

Same problem in de poploop. But here to effectively reverse anything you need to restart the string from the beginning. So write:

```
 "mov eax, %1;"
 "mov edx, %1;"
```

and use:

```
 ;;;;;;;;;;;;  "xor eax,eax;"
"poploop:"
 "cmp bx, 0;"
 "jz end;"
 "pop ecx;"
 "mov [edx], cl;"
 "inc edx;"
 "dec bx;"
 "jmp poploop;"
"end:"
```